# Can two combined events have a probability greater than the events themselves?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem, decision-trees

I'm presented with the following **conditional probability** problem:

> There are 2 bags with different numbers of **lemon and grape** candies:
>
> - Bag #1: **5 lemon candies, 5 grape candies** (10 candies total)
> - Bag #2: **4 lemon candies, 8 grape candies** (12 candies total)
>
> A person then performs the following events using the two bags **in succession** (i.e. dependent, yet mutually exclusive):
>
> 1. $\mathrm{Event \ I}$ - **Randomly pick a candy from Bag #1 and place it in Bag #2.** (hence, Bag #1 now has 1 less candy and Bag #2 has 1 more)
> 2. $\mathrm{Event \ J}$ - **Randomly pick another candy from Bag #1 and place it in Bag #2** (hence, Bag #1 now has 2 less candy, and Bag #2 has 2 more)
> 3. $\mathrm{Event \ K}$ - **Randomly pick the final candy from Bag #2**.

> Calculate $P(A)$, $P(B)$ and $P(A \cap B)$ given that $\mathrm{Event \ A}$ and $\mathrm{Event \ B}$ are described as follows:
>
> - $\mathrm{Event \ A}$ - **2 similar-flavored candies are picked from Bag #1**.
> - $\mathrm{Event \ B}$ - **The candy picked from Bag #2 is grape flavoured**.

Here's my attempt at calculating the required probabilities *(I haven't simplified the probabilities to keep the denominators similar to that of the total candies in each bag)*:

- Link to image: [Calculating P(A), P(B) and $P(A \cap B)$ w/ a tree diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQ4pb.png)

Based on the working given in the image, my answers are as follows:

- $P(A) = P(I \cap J) + P(\bar{I} \cap \bar{J}) = 2(\frac{5}{10} \times \frac{4}{9}) = \frac{4}{9}$
- $P(B) = P(\bar{K}) = P(\bar{K} \cap J \cap I) + P(\bar{K} \cap J \cap \bar{I}) + P(\bar{K} \cap \bar{J} \cap I) + P(\bar{K} \cap \bar{J} \cap \bar{I}) = \frac{9}{14}$
- $P(A \cap B) = P(\bar{K} \cap J \cap I) + P(\bar{K} \cap \bar{J} \cap \bar{I}) = \frac{2}{7}$

Here's the problem: **How come $P(A \cap B)$, i.e. $\frac{2}{7}$ is larger than $P(B)$, i.e. $\frac{9}{14}$**?

**Any corrections or advice will be highly appreciated.**

Comment: $\frac 27$, which is $\frac 4{14}$, is not larger than $\frac 9{14}$.

Comment: Actually $2/7<9/14$.

Comment: Oh wow, I'm so sorry for the trouble  - thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically speaking of

> Can two combined events have a probability greater than the events themselves?

if by this you mean "Can it be that $P(A \cap B) \gt P(A)$ or $P(A \cap B) \gt P(B)$?", the answer is no, by monotonicity of measures